# invoking an if…then function on a d3 node

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to call a conditional function in d3 and having trouble getting this code working.

My d3 code:

```
//create a div element within #container for each object
day = d3.select("#container").selectAll("div")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
        .append("div");
```

and I'd like to add a `p` element with different text depending on the object's `date` property:

```
//get today's date
var today = new Date();

//if after today
if (Date.parse(d.date) > today) {

    //print 'after today!'
    day.append('p').text(function(d) { return "after today!" });

//otherwise
} else {

    //print 'today or before'
    day.append('p').text(function(d) { return "today or before!" });
};
```

Can someone help me get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention what format `d.date` is in.  If it's already a date, just do:

```
day
 .append('p')
 .text(function(d) { 
   return (d.date.getTime() > Date.now()) ? "after today!" : "before today!";
 });
```

If it's not a date, convert to a date then call `getTime()`

**EDITS**

For the case you describe in your comments use a `.each`:

```js
var data = [1,0,1];
      
var div = d3.select('body')
  .selectAll('div')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('div')
  .each(function(d){
    var self = d3.select(this);
    if (d === 1){
      self.append('p')
        .text('Hi Mom!')
    } else {
      self.append('img')
        .attr('src','https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png')
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think this is closer to what I'm aiming for, but what if I only want to render the `p` element if `d.date is < Date.now()` and something else—say, an `img` element—if `d.date > Date.now()`? (I actually want to render an `img` element within an `a` element in the first scenario, and only an `img` element—no `a`— in the latter)

Comment: @SergioHernandez, see edits above for you new question.

Answer (score 0):

Attached is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nkqL4c26/7/.

JS:

```
//sample data:
var data = [
    {'date': "Sat Nov 15 2015 08:09:49 GMT+0530"},
    {'date': "Sat Nov 14 2015 08:09:49 GMT+0530"},
    {'date': "Sat Nov 13 2015 08:09:49 GMT+0530"},
    {'date': "Sat Nov 12 2015 08:09:49 GMT+0530"},
    {'date': "Sat Nov 11 2015 08:09:49 GMT+0530"}
];

d3.select("#container")
    .data(data, function(d, i ) { return d +i;})
    .enter()
    .append('p')
    .text(function(d) {
        var self = d3.select(this);
        return (Date.parse(d.date) > Date.now()) ? 
                " after today!"
                :" today or before!";
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">  </div>
```

**Edits made by @sergio**

ETA: What I'm actually trying to do here is append an `img` tag within an `a` tag if the date is before today's date, and only the `img` tag (without a link) if it's after today's date. I think this is the behavior I'm looking for, but I'm not sure my syntax is right:

```
day.append(function(d) {
    return (Date.parse(d.date) > Date.now()) ? 
        ('img').attr('src', 'img/inactive.png') : 
        ('a').attr('href', d.url)
            .append('img').attr('src', 'img/active.png');
});
```

Comment: hmm, that didn't work. I think the problem is how I'm invoking the function? I have `.data().enter().append('div').call(function(d) { if(Date.parse(d.date) … };`  when I do `console.log(d.date)` I'm getting `undefined`

Comment: also what does console.log(d) print ? meaning where is d being defined ?

Comment: d.date is part of the data... It's a JSON array and each object has a "date" property formatted at as YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: @SergioHernandez if you don't have answer yet please check the updated fiddle in this solution. Thanks !